# How to dispose a memory stream that is created down the callstack

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a function that uses MemoryStream and a caller that calls the function. The memory stream can only be disposed once the caller finish the execution

```
public MyDocument PrepareDocument()
{
    var documentImageStream = new MemoryStream();
    ...
    document.registerImages(documentImageStream);
    return document;
}

public void Render()
{
    var document = PrepareDocument();
    var file = document.Render();
    // Only at this point can the memory streams be disposed
}
```

I believe I have to dispose the stream but what is the correct way to do so?

- Do I explicitly modify the callee to output a list of streams to be closed as part of the function return signature `public MyDocumentAndStreamsToBeDisposed PrepareDocument()`
- Do I `out` a list of streams to be closed as a kind of "optional" output data?

both ways seems not clean to me as `public MyDocument PrepareDocument()` really should just prepare and return a document from my perspective

Or there is a clever way to use `using` statements that I am not ware of?

Thank you a lot

Comment: First off, `MemoryStream` only implements `IDisposable` because the base `Stream` object does. You don't actually need to dispose it -- it doesn't own anything which needs to be disposed, and disposing it does nothing

Comment: If you control `MyDocument`, I'd give that a `Dispose` method which disposes all streams passed into `RegisterImages`. That is, `MyDocument` takes ownership of any streams passed to it

Comment: @canton7 " Unfortunately MyDocument is from 3rd party. It is Gembox's Excelfile that would like to keep registered image until the Rendering moment

Comment: Would it work if `Render` manages the stream? i.e: `using var stream = new MemoryStream(); var document = PrepareDocument(stream);` ?

Comment: @Nope I would like to go that route also. But does it work with a List of streams? Since PrepareDocument is there because it had to locate and register multiple image streams it was rather complex to keep in one single function/layer. Or maybe I should create a class StreamsToDispose that implement IDisposable?

Comment: @qkhanhpro Have you looked at the source code of `registerImages` ? Does it actually keep a reference to the streams? Maybe it just extracts the images?

Comment: @Magnus I do not have access to the source code but put using directly inside the calle makes .Render throw stream closed exception

Comment: A third party library names a class "MyDocument"? Thats sound wrong and i can't find a reference to a registerImages method in the mentioned Library (Also a 3rd Party Library would use Upper Case names) It feels like you have written an abstraction around the mentioned Excelfile class and i don't see a problem extending your abstraction with an IDisposable implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe I have to dispose the stream

While disposing everything implementing IDisposable should be done in general, there are some exceptions where it is less important. One example is `Task` that only needs [disposal in special circumstances](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/). Another is MemoryStream, since the only resource it owns is memory, and that is freed regardless if it is disposed or not.

If `document.registerImages` takes a `stream`, and keeps a reference to this, it should probably assume ownership of the stream. I.e. `MyDocument` needs to implement `IDisposable` and dispose the stream in its dispose method. If `document.registerImages` takes a memory stream, that is probably not needed.

But in that case, is a memory stream really the right thing to use? Maybe a `byte[]` or a `Memory<byte>` would fit better? You might even have multiple methods, one that takes a `Memory<byte>` and a helper that takes a stream, copes the data to an array, and calls the other method.

if `MyDocument` is a third party class that is poorly designed, i.e. keeps references to streams without assuming ownership, you can either make sure to only ever give it memory streams. Or you could create a wrapper class that owns both the streams, and the document that needs to use the streams, and ensure that this is object is disposed.

I would not recommend returning multiple objects, or use out parameters to return a disposable object. If there is anything to dispose I want to be able to use a 'using' statement to dispose it, i.e. `using var myObject = CreateDisposableObject(...)`, or `using(CreateRegistration(myObject)){...}`. Returning a tuple, or using out parameters break this pattern.